# How to find Best Price for a Deck of Collectible Cards?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

### Or *The Traveling Salesman plays Magic!*

*I think this is a rather interesting algorithmic challenge. Curious if anyone has any good suggestions for solving it, or if it is already solvable in a known way.*

[TCGPlayer.com](http://TCGPlayer.com/) sells collectible cards for a variety of games, including *Magic the Gathering*. Instead of just selling cards from their inventory they are actually a *re-seller from multiple vendors* (50+). Each vendor has a **different inventory** of cards and a **different price per card**. Each vendor also charges a **flat rate for shipping** (usually). Given all of that, how would one find the best price for a deck of cards (say 40 - 100 cards)?

Just finding the best price for each card doesn't work because if you order 10 cards from 10 different vendors then you **pay shipping 10 times**, but if you order all 10 from one vendor you only **pay shipping once**.

The other night I wrote a simple HTML Scraper (using [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)) that grabs all the different prices for each card, and then finds all the vendors that carry all the cards in the deck, totals the price of the cards from each vendor and sorts by price. That was really easy. The total prices ended up being near the total median price for all the cards.

I did notice that some of the individual cards ended up being much higher than the median price. That raises the question of splitting an order over multiple vendors, but only if enough savings could be made by splitting the order up to cover the additional shipping (each added vendor adds another shipping charge).

Logically it seems that the best price will probably only involve a few different vendors, but if **the cards are expensive enough ([and some are](http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/magic_single_card.asp?cn=Jace,%20the%20Mind%20Sculptor))** then in theory ordering each card from a different vendor could still result in enough savings to justify all the extra shipping.

If you were going to tackle this how would you do it? Pure **brute force** figuring every possible combination of card / vendor combinations? A process that is more likely to be done in my lifetime would seem to involve a **methodical series of estimates** over a fixed number of iterations. I have a couple ideas, but am curious what others might suggest.

I am looking more for the algorithm than actual code. I am currently using .NET though, if that makes any difference.

[image: Jace, the Mind Sculptor]

Comment: Isn't this basically the knapsack problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: definitely has an NP-complete flavor to it. however, many of those problems have efficient approximations for particular assumptions about the input - that's what I take Jim's question to be about.

Comment: <joke>You will probably want to assign `Jace.vendor=eBay` by default.</joke>

Comment: Just as a side note, if you're writing this you might want to consider applying the concepts to the bots on MTGO, pulling prices from [http://www.mtgolibrary.com/wiki.php](http://www.mtgolibrary.com/wiki.php).  This has the added layer of complexity in that often the bots listing there do not actually have the cards listed, but simplifies things by removing shipping from the equation entirely.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the knapsack problem because (a) you want to 'bring everything' with you, not maximize what goes in your bag, and (b) the shipping cost can drastically change the value of cards on the fly.  If I bought card A from vendor X and then try and buy card B from vendor Y, it will be expensive because of the shipping, but if I go back and buy card A from vendor Y, it reduces the cost of buying card B from Y.

Answer (score 6):

I would just be greedy.

Assume that you are going to eat the shipping cost and buy from all vendors.  Work out the absolute lowest price you get.  Then for each vendor work out how much being able to buy some cards from them versus someone else saves you.  Order the vendors by shipping - incremental savings.

Starting with the vendors who provide the least value, axe that vendor, redistribute their cards to the other vendors, and recalculate incremental savings.  Wash, rinse, and repeat until your most marginal vendor is saving you money.

This should find a good solution but is not guaranteed to find the best solution.  Finding the absolute best solution, though, seems likely to be NP-hard.

Comment: I agree, "solving" seems to be NP-hard, but I think you have a nice solution for approximating. I actually started trying to think of a way to start from each card with with the best price, but couldn't come up with a possible solution. I like this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is isomorphic to the uncapacitated [facility location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location) problem.

- card in the deck : client
- vendor : possible facility location
- vendor shipping rate : cost of opening a facility at a location
- cost of a card with a particular vendor : "distance" from a client to a facility

Facility location is a well-studied problem in the combinatorial optimization literature.

Comment: Do you know where I might find some sample code or a description of the algorithm to approximate a solution in facility location?

Comment: The first thing I would try is integer programming. This module http://code.google.com/p/python-zibopt/source/browse/trunk/examples/facility-location.py?spec=svn88&r=88 demonstrates the most obvious formulation. There are many different solvers for integer programs, and with any luck there will be one to your liking.

Comment: Googling [facility location optimization non-metric] results in citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/… , which has wonderful pseudocode for an greedy algorithm (which only guarantees a factor of 1.86, but that's in pathological cases) in section 3. The inputs are defined in section 2; for example there is an input of facilitySetupCost(cards) which you'd define as [baseShipping, baseShipping+shippingPerCard, baseShipping+2*shippingPerCard, ...].

Comment: You actually need the capacitated version (if it means what I think it means), since vendors only carry only a fixed number of cards. Note that a solution therefore may not exist, though this is impossibly rare in practice (unless you make a typo).

Comment: @ninjagecko I take it the deck has duplicate cards then? I don't think that's the canonical capacitated version, but it's still easy to formulate as an integer program, though the relaxation quality will suffer with more duplicates and make the solver less efficient.

Comment: @adlskf - There are duplicate cards. The cards could come from different vendors too (if the cheapest vendor doesn't have enough inventory), which means different prices.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? using the capacitated version I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I myself have pondered this. Consider the following:

> If it takes you a week to figure out,
>   code, and debug and algorithm that
>   only provides a 1% discount, would you
>   do it?

The answer is probably "No" (unless you're spending your entire life savings on cards, in which case you may be crazy). =)... or Amazon.com

Consequently, there is already an easy approximating algorithm:

```
Wait until you're buying lots of cards (reduce the shipping overhead).
Buy the cards from 3 vendors:
    - the two with the cheapest-but-most-diverse inventories
    - a third which isn't really cheap but definitely has every card you'd want.
Optimize accordingly (for each card, buy from the cheaper one).
Also consider local vendors you could just walk to, pre-constructed decks, and trading.
```

Based on firsthand and second experience, I can say you will find that you can get the median price with perhaps a few dollars more shipping you could otherwise, while still getting around median on each. You will find that you may have to pay a tiny bit more for understocked cards, but this will be few and far between, and the shipping savings will make up for it.

I recall the old programming adage: **"Never optimize, until it's absolutely necessary; chances are you won't need to, or would have optimized the wrong thing."** (e.g. your time is a resource too, and also has monetary value)

edit: Given that, this is an amazingly cool problem and one should solve it if one has time.

Comment: I strongly disagree. There's optimization and optimization. If you optimize your code in the sense of "let's make this loop run faster"  I agree. Here, you're dealing with a question of computational complexity, which means you're not talking about %, but whether code that runs in 1 second for n cards will run 2 seconds or 10 seconds for 2n cards (or will blow up your system if by some freak chance you happen to look up 10n cards)

Comment: I actually disagree with the conjecture that it isn't worth solving the problem because it might not justify itself from an actual savings point of view. I solve a lot of problems just because they seem like interesting problems to solve. I consider it the programmer's curse - the desire to write a program to solve all the problems they encounter. Although Thomas Edison agrees with you since he would only pursue an invention he thought people would buy.

Comment: Nicolas78: No, the poster explicitly asks how he should trade off computational complexity for a reasonable estimate. "If you were going to tackle this how would you do it? Pure brute force figuring every...? ...to be done in my lifetime would seem to involve a methodical series of estimates over a fixed number of iterations. I have a couple ideas, but am curious what others might suggest." As you can see, this this answer is acceptable. An approximating answer is an answer. Also this approximation obviously runs in `O(n)` time, so no optimization is needed as you imply.

Comment: Jim: Totally agreed. I never said it was never worth solving. =) I myself have often wondered about it and am really enjoying other answers. I am just pointing out there is already a simple approximating solution. (edit: hmm, maybe I do imply that... edited, thank you)

Comment: ninja: yea sorry I misinterpreted your 1% discount as 1% saving in running time. which, reading it again, doesn't make a lot of sense both from the term "discount" and from the fact that you actually provide an approximation that doesn't sacrifice time but money. I still believe some optimization might be worthwhile depending on how much cards you're gonna buy, but have to take back "strong disagreement" because that was against something you actually didn't say ;)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! :)

So if we have n cards and m vendors, the brute force approach might have to check up to n^m combinations, right (a bit less since not each vendor has each card, but I guess that doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things ;).

Let's for a second assume each vendor has each card and then see later-on how things change if they don't.

1. find the cheapest one-vendor solution.
2. order the cards by price, find the most expensive card that's cheaper at another vendor.
3. for all cards from vendor 1, move them to vendor 2 if they're cheaper there.
4. if having added vendor 2 doesn't make the order cheaper, undo and terminate, otherwise repeat from step 2

So if one vendor doesn't have all cards, you have to start with a multi-vendor situation. For each vendor, you might start by buying all cards that exist there, then apply the algorithm to the remaining cards.

Obviously, you may not be able to exploit all subtleties in the pricing with this method. But if we assume that a large portion of the price differences is made up by individual high-price cards, I think you can find a reasonable solution with this way.

---

Ok after writing all this I realized, the n^m assumption is actually wrong. 
Once you have chosen a set of vendors to buy from, you can simply choose the cheapest vendor for each card. This is a great advantage because the individual choices of where to buy each card don't interfere with each other.

What does this mean for our problem? From the first look of it, it means that the selection of dealers is the problem (in terms of computational complexity), not the individual allocation of your buying choices. So instead of n^m, you got 2^m possible configurations in the worst case. So what we need is a heuristic for choosing vendors rather than choosing individual cards. Which might make the heuristic from above actually even more justifiable.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but I like the way you explained it. Only 2^m? That isn't so bad.

Comment: The other problem with your attack

Comment: The problem with your stated attack is that it's possible that buying all possible cards from vendor 2 may be more expensive, but buying a few cheaper cards may be less expensive. For example, say vendor 2 has a sale on cards starting with the letter A, but is more expensive on everything else. It may be cheaper to buy A cards from vendor 2, but also including the other cards pushes it back up over the cost of vendor 1. That's really the problem. Any combination of cards from a vendor has the potential to be cheaper than the same set from another vendor.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The first card I find is the most expensive card that's cheaper at vendor 2 than at vendor 1. Then I move this and all other cards that are cheaper at vendor 2 to vendor 2. No need to include other cards. Or am I getting you wrong?

Answer (score 1):

my algorithm goes like this

1. for each card calculate the average price available i.e sum of the price available from each vendor divide by the no of vendors.
2. now for that card select a vendor that offers less than or equal to average price.
3. now for each card we will have the list of vendors. now go for the intersection this way we will end up with series of vendor providing the maximxum no of cards at average or below average price.

i'm still thinking over the next steps but im putting the rough idea over here

- now we are left with cards which are providing us single card. for such cards we will look into the price list of alredy short listed vendors with max no of cards and if the price diff is less than the shipping cost the we add the card to that vendors list.

i know this will require a huge optimization. but this what i have roghly figured out hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

1. Calculate the average price per ordered card across all vendors.
2. For each vendor that has at least one of the cards, calculate the total savings for all cards in the order as the difference between each card's price at that vendor and the average price.
3. Start with the vendor with the highest total savings and select all of those cards from that vendor.
4. Continue to select vendors with the next highest total savings until you have all of the cards in the order selected. Skip vendors that don't have cards that you still need.
5. From the selected list of vendors, redistribute the card purchases to the vendors with the best price for that card.
6. From the remaining list of vendors, and if the list is small enough, you could then brute force any vendors with a low card count to see if you could move the cards to other vendors to eliminate the shipping cost.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote this exact thing last year.  The first thing I do after loading all the prices is I weed out my card pool:

- Each vendor can have multiple
  versions of each card, as there are
  reprints.  Find the cheapest one.
- Eliminate any card where the card value is greater than the cheapest card+shipping combo.  That is, if I can buy the card cheaper as a one-off to a vendor than I can by adding it to an existing order from your store, I will buy it from the other vendor.
- Eliminate any vendor whose offering I can buy cheaper (for every card) from another vendor.  Basically, if another vendor out-prices you on every card, and on the total + shipping, then you are gone.

Unfortunately, this still leaves a huge pool.
Then I do some sorting and some brute-force-depth-first summing and some pruning and eventually end up with a result.

Anyway, I tuned it up to the point that I can do 70 cards and, within a minute, get within 5% of the optimal goal.  And in an hour, less than 2%.  And then, a couple of days later, the actual, final result.

I am going to read more about facility planning.  Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 1):

What about using genetic algorithm? I think I'll try that one myself. You might manipulate the pool by adding both a chromosome with lowest prices, and another with lowest shipping costs.

BTW, did you finally implement any of the solutions presented here? which one? why?

Cheers!

Comment: I did not end up implementing any of them, there are a lot of cool sounding algorithms here.